# React native state not updating while working with flatlist

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have declared a variable as

```
var state = ['flase'];
```

I am trying to set value to true inside a function which is called onPress.

```
const handleSelectedOption=(option,i)=>{
        if(option===item.answer){
             state[i]=true;
            console.log("Right answer:"+option);
            console.log("i value"+i);//giving index value
            console.log("state value:"+state[i]);// giving true
        }else{
          state[i]=true;
            console.log("wrong answer");
            console.log("Show Option"+option);
            console.log("Show answer"+item.answer);
        }
    };
```

I am using that value for condition to show two more  text once something is clicked.

I am basically creating a quiz app which will show answer and explanation once a option is selected for each question. This does not have score to update. Single question and answer. Showing results in flatlist.

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        {quiz.loading ?
            <View style={styles.loading}>
                <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
            </View>
            :
            <FlatList
            contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
                data={quiz}
               // renderItem={renderItem}
                renderItem={SingleQuiz}
                ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
                ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
                ListEmptyComponent={renderEmpty}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.2}
                onEndReached={fetchMoreData}
                 //extraData={state}
            />
        }

    </SafeAreaView>
)
```

this is my SingleQuiz.js file

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Linking
} from "react-native";

const windowWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;

function SingleQuiz  ({ item })  {
   
 
   const optionValue=['optionA','optionB','optionC','optionD']
  var state = ['flase'];
   console.log("State value inside singquiz:"+state);
    const handleSelectedOption=(option,i)=>{
        if(option===item.answer){
             state[i]=true;
            console.log("Right answer:"+option);
            console.log("i value"+i);
            console.log("state value:"+state[i]);
        }else{
          state[i]=true;
            console.log("wrong answer");
            console.log("Show Option"+option);
            console.log("Show answer"+item.answer);
        }
    };



  
 
    return (
      <View style={{
        backgroundColor:'#006666',
        //borderRadius: 5,
        height: windowHeight,
        width: windowWidth,
        paddingTop:50,
        paddingRight:30,
        paddingLeft:20,
        marginLeft: 2,
        marginRight: 2, }} key={item.id}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 28,color:'#ffffff'}}>Question:  {item.question}</Text>
      <Text>{"\n"}</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 20,color:'#ffffff'}} onPress={()=>{handleSelectedOption(optionValue[0],item.id)}}>A. {item.optionA}</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 20,color:'#ffffff'}} onPress={()=>handleSelectedOption(optionValue[1])}>B. {item.optionB}</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 20,color:'#ffffff'}} onPress={()=>handleSelectedOption(optionValue[2])}>C. {item.optionC}</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 20,color:'#ffffff'}} onPress={()=>handleSelectedOption(optionValue[3])}>D. {item.optionD}</Text>
      <Text>Value: {String(state[item.id])}</Text>
      {state[item.id] && <Text style={{fontSize: 20,color:'#ffffff'}}>Answer: {item.answer}</Text>}
      {state[item.id] &&  <Text style={{fontSize: 20,color:'#ffffff'}}>Details: {item.explanation}</Text>}
     
     
    </View>
    )
  
  }


export default SingleQuiz
```

I tried to see the value here

```
<Text>Value: {String(state[item.id])}</Text> // showing undefined
```

So basically this part is not working for the app,

```
{state[item.id] && <Text style={{fontSize: 20,color:'#ffffff'}}>Answer: {item.answer}</Text>}
          {state[item.id] &&  <Text style={{fontSize: 20,color:'#ffffff'}}>Details: {item.explanation}</Text>}
```

I have wasted almost two working around it can anyonle please help me out. Thank You in advance.

Comment: That's not how you use the state in a React function component. The `useState` hook should be used instead. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Also it's false not 'flase'

Comment: useState hook is an invalid call there. 'flase' is my bad